Dlt pipeline have a high latency
In the case of a small amount of data, it takes about 5 minutes for the Dlt pipeline to perform end-to-end tasks, and the dlt pipeline contains 78 tables, with the data volume of each table being about thousands of rows. Why is it so slow? Is there any optimization method?
I tried to split the dlt pipeline, reducing the number of tables in each pipeline to 10, and it still took 2 minutes to complete the end-to-end task.

It depends on how much transformation you are doing. A few things which may help. You can check the the metrics and spark logs by going to the job compute section. Try adjusting the auto scale and node size settings. Also check that you are partitioning the data appropriately.
